# Embed youtube video into iOS facebook app browser

Tags: ios, facebook, youtube

I can embed a youtube video just fine in regular Safari, using the iframe api, a regular iframe embed code, and even the odd method of writing out the old object embed code and having safari recognise it and replace it with the HTML5 equivalent.

However- once a page is linked to from within the facebook app, which opens the browser built in to the app, the player does appear, but clicking on it turns the player into an inactive black box.

Is this a known restriction of facebook's built in browser? Even well known sites such as huffington post seem to suffer from this problem. I'm hoping it just has to do with this bug

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/youtube/report-a-technical-issue/iHd0NK33k-I

...but wanted to hear if anyone else here has some insight.

Comment: For example, try sharing http://www.buzzfeed.com/video/caitlincowie/surprising-facts-about-the-oscars, then clicking on the link on your phone- currently, the video won't play at all within the facebook app browser.

Comment: As a workaround, I'm going to link to the video on youtube.com, which *does* play within that browser, although that's far from ideal.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Everything was working fine yesterday morning, but not today. I'm guessing YT pushed an update to their embed player that broke things. Hope they get it fixed soon!

Comment: Plenty of people have now posted in the google group thread I linked to above, all reporting the same issue, so it really must be a YouTube problem. My workaround is in place now, and although it's not very nice to force the user to make an extra tap, and tap back to return to the app, it seems the only viable solution until it's fixed. If you want to see it in action, tap the "Real Challengers" story on the Mazda UK facebook page using the facebook app on an iPhone, as it's sensitive to the user agent.